# unable to download image from Firebase Storage via Picasso

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, picasso, firebase-storage

Steps:

1. Upload image to firebase Storage
2. getdownloadUrl, convert into string and store into firebase database

   ```
   Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl();
   String UriinString=downloadUrl.toString();
   ```
3. call saved url in string and load into image view via picasso, passing the context and url

   ```
   Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(currentURI).into(mindMapImage);
   ```

Comment: What's your question/problem? It will probably be a lot easier to help you if you provide a [minimal, complete snippet that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). A lot of information is missing between the two snippets you now provide, making it very difficult to figure out what is going on (and this what is going wrong).

Comment: Picasso.with(this).load(/* url of image */).into(/*your imageview id*/);